# d3 v5 tree zoom, drag, and reset

Tags: d3.js, svg, angular7

I am using d3 version 5 for tree layout. I need to add zoom, pan, drag, and reset on tree. I have used the following:

```
this.svg = d3.select(this.chartContainer.nativeElement).append("svg")
    .attr("width", this.width + this.margin.right + this.margin.left)
    .attr("height", this.height + this.margin.top + this.margin.bottom)
    .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", ()=> {
      this.svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
    }))
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("
          + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")");
```

I am able to zoom with mouse wheel, drag and drop over the tree. I am unable to zoom with two fingers. And on Reset, it comes back to original state. But when I click anywhere tree moved to old position. I am using the following for reset:

```
this.svg.transition().duration(750).attr("transform", d3.zoomIdentity.translate(this.margin.left, this.margin.top));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to select g instead of svg to get my zooming and panning to work the way that I wanted:

```
D3.select('svg')
      .call(D3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([-5, 8])
        .extent([[0, 0], [300, 300]])
        .on('zoom', () => {

          D3.selectAll('g')
            .attr('transform', D3.event.transform);


          // this.svg.call(D3.zoom().transform, transform);
          if (has('root.children', this) && this.root.children.length > 50) {
            this.updateAfterInit(this.root);
          } else {
            this.updateAfterInit(this.root);
          }

          // this.centerNode(this.root);
        })
        .filter(() => {

          const foundNode = this.N.findNodeByID(D3.event.srcElement.id.split('_')[1])

          if ( !!foundNode && D3.event.type === 'dblclick' && foundNode.data.type === 'SearchRelationspec') {
            return false;
          } else {
            return !D3.event.target.classList.contains('drawarea') && D3.event.type === 'dblclick';
          }
        })
```